# SQL Handling Nullible Foreign Keys in Where Clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

Lets say I have a table named my_table with primary_key table_pk and with three nullible fields (foreign keys) named X_fk, Y_fk, and Z_fk respectively, and one other field called data. Tables X, Y, and Z all have a primary key field and a name field (e.g. {X_pk, X_name}, {Y_pk, Y_name}, {Z_pk, Z_name}).

I want a query that uniquely returns a row from my_table given the names in tables X, Y, and Z.

```
SELECT table_pk 
FROM my_table 
WHERE 
    X_fk = (SELECT X_pk FROM X WHERE X_name = ?) 
  AND 
    Y_fk = (SELECT Y_pk FROM Y WHERE Y_name = ?) 
  AND 
    Z_fk = (SELECT Z_pk FROM Z WHERE Z_name = ?)
```

This doesn't work though when I want to find the row (X_Name, Y_Name, Z_Name) = ('XXX', 'YYY', NULL) because Z_fk = NULL can never result in TRUE. How can I modify the above query to pull out a unique entry from the table accounting for unique entries where some of the foreign keys are NULL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT min(table_pk)
FROM my_table 
WHERE 
    ((X_fk = (SELECT X_pk FROM X WHERE X_name = ?)) OR (? IS NULL AND X_fk IS NULL))
AND 
    ((Y_fk = (SELECT Y_pk FROM Y WHERE Y_name = ?)) OR (? IS NULL AND Y_fk IS NULL)) 
AND 
    ((Z_fk = (SELECT Z_pk FROM Z WHERE Z_name = ?)) OR (? IS NULL AND Z_fk IS NULL))
```

Comment: Deleting mine and giving +1.  This seems like a more complete version of what I was trying to do.

Comment: You wouldn't need a MIN since there is only one table in the FROM clause

Comment: @cyberkiwi: I thought author needed only one row. If this combination of fields is unique, min is not needed.

Comment: quite right, the (X_fk, Y_fk, Z_fk) tuple forms a unique key... I'll give this a try tomorrow, looks to me like it should work though!

Answer (score 2):

Same answer as LukLed, but with the inputs being bound only once from the front end

```
SELECT table_pk 
FROM my_table
cross join (select ? iX, ? iY, ? iZ) i
WHERE 
    ((i.iX is null and X_fk is null) OR X_fk = (SELECT X_pk FROM X WHERE X_name = i.iX))
  AND 
    ((i.iY is null and Y_fk is null) or Y_fk = (SELECT Y_pk FROM Y WHERE Y_name = i.iY))
  AND 
    ((i.iZ is null and Z_fk is null) or Z_fk = (SELECT Z_pk FROM Z WHERE Z_name = i.iZ))
```

This looks shorter but doesn't do indexes any good (assuming -1 is not a valid value).

```
SELECT table_pk 
FROM my_table
WHERE 
    Isnull(X_fk,-1) = isnull((SELECT X_pk FROM X WHERE X_name = ?),-1)
  AND 
    Isnull(Y_fk,-1) = Isnull((SELECT Y_pk FROM Y WHERE Y_name = ?),-1)
  AND 
    Isnull(Z_fk,-1) = Isnull((SELECT Z_pk FROM Z WHERE Z_name = ?),-1)
```

Comment: +1: Although it looks worse, you have parameters used one time.

Comment: hm... what the heck is cross join? :)

Comment: @vicatcu, same as if you replace the words `cross join` with a single `comma`.  It produces a Cartesian product between two tables.  Since i is defined as a single row, 3 column table, it is used only to column-ize the inputs.